# What do we do with questions which are spoiler by nature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, spoilers

We really need to agree on this one early on. What do we do with questions who by nature are spoilers? I mean, not part of the question, but the entire question.

For instance, asking about a character who's identity is only revealed later in the manga (but not the anime). Even the question's title itself may contain major spoilers in that case.

The source of the problem comes from the unique relationship between manga and anime. The manga would always be ahead of the anime, and there would always be people only viewing one of the two.

Therefore, questions on topics entirely revealed on the manga is likely to produce heavy spoilers for viewers of the anime.

How do we deal with those? The only way I can think of is implement a feature to mark an entire question as spoilerish.

Comment: there has to be someway to tag (or mark otherwise) the whole question and possible set of answers as spoilers, so that potential victims may ignore such a tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think a good rule of thumb is this:

- Make sure the title of the question is NOT inherently spoilery. (One of [the moderators](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/4/aarthi) has [already](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19/do-we-know-what-happens-to-spike-at-the-end-of-cowboy-bebop#comment48_19) [requested this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12/list-of-surviving-uchiha#comment47_12) on the site a couple of times.)
- Warn for spoilers in the first line or two of the post.
- Mark the main part of the question inside spoiler block quotes ( which is `> !` for those unaware)
- Try to include some non-spoilery background to make the question discoverable long term.

A good example is [Where is Stark Tower located?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16517/where-is-stark-tower-located) on SciFi. There's some background to make the question discoverable, but the main part of the question (which is spoilery for *The Avengers* film) is hidden under spoiler tags.

**[EDIT]**: I edited [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/214/why-isnt-tobi-blind-yet) to demonstrate the above as well as I could.

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: +1 The question you edited is a *perfect* example of how questions should be handled to avoid spoilers.

Answer (score 3):

I would say we should follows these do's and don't's.

- **DO** Avoid major spoilers in titles
- **DO** Warn for spoilers at the top of the post
- **DO NOT** Put your post in spoiler markup
- **DO NOT** Put answers in spoiler markup
- **DO NOT Tag the question with a meta [spoiler](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) tag!**
- **DO NOT** Avoid spoilers in the title so much that the question content cannot be understood from the title

The idea is that once you've warned at the top of the post, any further reading is at the user's own risk. No further spoiler markup is needed.